# How can I achieve fading of overflowing child elements in a row container with no width limit in Flutter, without using RichText?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a row container with no width limit, and when its child elements overflow and need to wrap, fade the overflowing child elements.

[image]

My current solution is to use Rich.text, but it doesn't feel like a good idea. It is for text. Do you have a better solution?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoWrap extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoWrap({
    super.key,
    required this.children,
  });

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text.rich(
      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
      softWrap: false,
      TextSpan(
        children: [for (final child in children) WidgetSpan(child: child)],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

fade | ellipsis | clip overflowing child elements without using Rich.text

Answer (score 0):

```
return OverflowBox(
      minWidth: 0,
      minHeight: 0,
      maxWidth: double.infinity,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          for (final child in children)
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
```

Try this,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using 2 different widgets.

1. `OverflowBox` widget.

Here's the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoWrap extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoWrap({
    super.key,
    required this.children,
  });

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: children.map((child) => _fadeOnOverflow(child)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _fadeOnOverflow(Widget child) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        OverflowBox(
          maxWidth: double.infinity,
          child: child,
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            width: 15,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.transparent, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

2. `ClipRect` widget

You can use this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoWrap extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoWrap({
    super.key,
    required this.children,
  });

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: children.map((child) => _fadeOnOverflow(child)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _fadeOnOverflow(Widget child) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.transparent, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)],
          ),
        ),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working need size;
`[log] RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#f679c relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
      Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'
`

Comment: Give width to childs like this
child: SizedBox( 
        width: 100.0,
        child: child,
      ),

Comment: Thank you, but the width of the child element is dynamic, it cannot have a fixed width

Comment: Then use flexible with SizedBox (maxWidth: double.infinity)

Comment: You can use Expanded widget.

Comment: You can use Expanded widget. 

>>>>>>>>>>

OverflowBox is not working, I am now using RichText as child element of Expanded